# $(this).context.cells.each does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my javascript code:

```
$("#gridProcessDetail tbody").on('click', 'tr', function () {
 $(this).context.cells.each(function (ind) {
   var txt = $(this).html();
  });
}
```

`$(this).context.cells` returns two cells but it says:

```
 html is not is not a function at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (Invoice:472)
    at HTMLTableSectionElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)
    at HTMLTableSectionElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)
```

Comment: Why don't you use `$('td', this).each()`? You are mixing jQuery APIs with DOM APIs for no sensible reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`context`](http://api.jquery.com/context/) returns a DOM node (deprecated in 1.10.0), and the jQuery `.each()` function is attempting to iterate over the DOM nodes.

It would be better to change your code to:

```
$("#gridProcessDetail tbody").on('click', 'tr', function () {
 $(this).children().each(function (ind) {
   var txt = $(this).html();
  });
});
```